# List of techniques to evaluate limits?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'd like to make a complete list of techniques to evaluate a limit.

- Definition of the limit
- Continuous functions
- Algebra of limits
- Addition, multiplication, division
- Composition
- Inverse function
- Showing inequalities
- Squeeze theorem
- Rewriting, try to factor out common factors in numerator and
  denominator
- Rationalizing the denominator
- Substitutions, in particular the $1/t$ substitution.
- Use of derivatives, l'Hôpital's rule and Taylor series.
- If $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)=\infty$ then $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)^{g(x)} = e^{\lim_{x\to a} g(x)[f(x)-1]}$$
- for $$0^0\quad and\quad \infty^0 \quad form \implies $$
     $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)^{g(x)}=e^{\lim_{x\to a}[g(x) \log_e{f(x)}]}$$

However the list seems so short. Are there any other good strategies or techniques to solve limits?

Comment: One does not _solve_ limits; one _evaluates_ limits. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Does the list seem too short? It depends what do you mean by "Algebra of limits". Is it only addition, multiplication and division? If so, you should add the Theorem of Limit of Composite Function and Theorem of Limit of Inverse function to your list.

Comment: This [13 February 2000 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=225974) of mine contains a summary of a hand-written handout on various limit methods that I used in the late 1990s when teaching very strong high school students at [LSMSA](http://www.lsmsa.edu/).

Comment: The list will get longer if it includes techniques to evaluate infinite series, products and continued fractions, and infinitely nested radicals, since they are respectively defined as the limits of finite series, products and continued fractions, and finitely nested radicals.

Comment: I think you have listed all the techniques used to evaluate limits. Perhaps you should mention explicitly the use of standard limits like $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x} = 1$. I wonder what else could be used to evaluate a limit

Comment: Your last result regarding $\{f(x)\}^{g(x)}$ is not any special technique, but should be categorized under "Algebra of limits: compositiion". Here one takes logs of the expression and then evaluates the limit of $g(x)\log f(x)$ and if comes out to be $L$, the final answer is $e^{L}$. The result you mention follows from standard limit $(1/x)\log(1 + x) \to 1$ as $x \to 0$. Thus "algebra of limits" is a far more powerful technique than many think but unfortunately it is not widely used or advertized.

Comment: Maybe mention asymptotic analysis (as a general strategy encompassing Taylor series, "try to factor out common factors in numerator and denominator")?

Comment: @Dave L. Renfro the link you gave seems dead...

Comment: @Cheng: After looking for over 30 minutes, I believe this was a sci.math post I made through the Math Forum portal in the early 2000s that never made it to those who accessed sci.math elsewhere (newsreaders, google-groups). This was a problem they had for about a year due to one of their several migrations (and URL changes, which wrecked havoc on all my previously made URL cites, something that happened maybe 3 different times between 1999 and the mid 2000s), and thus is not archived in google-groups. I have a .pdf scan of the original document -- send me an email to reply to if you want it.

Answer (score 3):

The list of techniques to evaluate a limit that you have given above covers most of the non-elementary limit problems. Below I have given a few results that will be helpful in evaluating certain limit problems$:$
$ \bullet \ $ Assume that $f:(-a,a) \setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \Re \ $. Then $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=l \ $ if and only if $ \ \lim_{x\to0}f(\sin(x))=l. $

$\bullet \ $ Assume that $f:(-a,a) \setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \Re \ $ . If $ \lim_{x\to0}f(x)=l \ $ then $ \lim_{x\to0}f(\left \vert {x} \vert \right) = l. $

$\bullet \ $ $ lim_{x\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x = e$

$\bullet$ $ lim_{x\to 0} (1+x)^\frac{1}{x} = e $